# Eigenvalues in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, eigenvector, eigenvalue

In MATLAB, when I run the command `[V,D] = eig(a)` for a symmetric matrix, the largest eigenvalue (and its associated vector) is located in last column. However, when I run it with a non-symmetric matrix, the largest eigenvalue is in the first column.

I am trying to calculate eigenvector centrality which requires that I take the compute the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue. So the fact that the largest eigenvalue appears in two separate places it makes it difficult for me to find the solution.

Comment: Is it that hard to explicitly search through the array of eigenvalues and grab the largest one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to find the index of the largest eigenvalue in `D`, which can easily be done using the function [DIAG](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/diag.html) to extract the main diagonal and the function [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) to get the maximum eigenvalue and the index where it occurs:

```
[V,D] = eig(a);
[maxValue,index] = max(diag(D));  %# The maximum eigenvalue and its index
maxVector = V(:,index);           %# The associated eigenvector in V
```

**NOTE:** As [woodchips points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291770/eigenvalues-in-matlab/3293855#3293855), you can have complex eigenvalues for non-symmetric matrices. When operating on a complex input `X`, the [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) function uses the magnitude of the complex number `max(abs(X))`. In the case of equal magnitude elements, the phase angle `max(angle(X))` is used.

Answer (score 16):

What I usually do is:

```
[V D] = eig(a);
[D order] = sort(diag(D),'descend');  %# sort eigenvalues in descending order
V = V(:,order);
```

Comment: This is a more general solution that is useful when computing PCA.

Comment: how to do this in `eigs`?

Answer (score 4):

Note that non-symmetric matrices tend to have complex eigenvalues.

```
eig(rand(7))
ans =
       3.2957              
     -0.22966 +    0.58374i
     -0.22966 -    0.58374i
     -0.38576              
      0.49064              
      0.17144 +    0.27968i
      0.17144 -    0.27968i
```

Also note that eig does not explicitly return sorted eigenvalues (although the underlying algorithm tends to produce them in a nearly sorted order, based on the magnitude of the eigenvalue), but even if you do do a sort, you need to understand how sort works on complex vectors.

```
sort(rand(5,1) + i*rand(5,1))
ans =
      0.42343 +    0.51539i
    0.0098208 +    0.76145i
      0.20348 +    0.88695i
      0.43595 +    0.83893i
       0.8225 +    0.91264i
```

Sort, when applied to complex inputs, works on the magnitude of the complex number.

Comment: +1 hadn't thought of complex numbers. I guess I usually only care about the real eigenvalues

Answer (score 1):

If you only care for the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue, isn't it better to use [`eigs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html)?

```
[V, D] = eigs( a, 1, 'lm' ); %// get first eigenvector with largest eigenvalue magnitude.
```