# MATLAB eig returns inverted signs sometimes

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, svd, eigenvector

I'm trying to write a program that gets a matrix `A` of any size, and SVD decomposes it:

```
A = U * S * V'
```

Where `A` is the matrix the user enters, `U` is an orthogonal matrix composes of the eigenvectors of `A * A'`, `S` is a diagonal matrix of the singular values, and `V` is an orthogonal matrix of the eigenvectors of `A' * A`.

Problem is: the MATLAB function `eig` sometimes returns the wrong eigenvectors.

This is my code:

```
function [U,S,V]=badsvd(A)
W=A*A';
[U,S]=eig(W);
max=0;
for i=1:size(W,1) %%sort
    for j=i:size(W,1)
        if(S(j,j)>max)
            max=S(j,j);
            temp_index=j;
        end
    end
    max=0;
    temp=S(temp_index,temp_index);
    S(temp_index,temp_index)=S(i,i);
    S(i,i)=temp;
    temp=U(:,temp_index);
    U(:,temp_index)=U(:,i);
    U(:,i)=temp;
end
W=A'*A;
[V,s]=eig(W);
max=0;
for i=1:size(W,1) %%sort
    for j=i:size(W,1)
        if(s(j,j)>max)
            max=s(j,j);
            temp_index=j;
        end
    end
    max=0;
    temp=s(temp_index,temp_index);
    s(temp_index,temp_index)=s(i,i);
    s(i,i)=temp;
    temp=V(:,temp_index);
    V(:,temp_index)=V(:,i);
    V(:,i)=temp;
end
s=sqrt(s);
end
```

My code returns the correct `s` matrix, and also "nearly" correct `U` and `V` matrices. But some of the columns are multiplied by -1. obviously if `t` is an eigenvector, then also `-t` is an eigenvector, but with the signs inverted (for some of the columns, not all) I don't get `A = U * S * V'`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Example: for the matrix `A=[1,2;3,4]` my function returns:

```
U=[0.4046,-0.9145;0.9145,0.4046]
```

and the built-in MATLAB `svd` function returns:

```
u=[-0.4046,-0.9145;-0.9145,0.4046]
```

Comment: I got it wrong. Sorry. I'm deleting my answer

Comment: related questions: [Could we get different solutions for eigenVectors from a matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041178/could-we-get-different-solutions-for-eigenvectors-from-a-matrix), [Does Matlab eig always returns sorted values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13704384/97160)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that eigenvectors are not unique. Multiplying by any constant, including `-1` (which simply changes the sign), gives another valid eigenvector. This is clear given the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of an eigenvector:

```
A·v = λ·v
```

MATLAB [chooses](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#zmw57dd0e122394) to normalize the eigenvectors to have a norm of 1.0, the sign is arbitrary:

> For `eig(A)`, the eigenvectors are scaled so that the norm of each is 1.0.
>   For `eig(A,B)`, `eig(A,'nobalance')`, and `eig(A,B,flag)`, the eigenvectors are not normalized

Now as you know, SVD and eigendecomposition are [related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition). Below is some code to test this fact. Note that `svd` and `eig` return results in different order (one sorted high to low, the other in reverse):

```
% some random matrix
A = rand(5);

% singular value decomposition
[U,S,V] = svd(A);

% eigenvectors of A'*A are the same as the right-singular vectors
[V2,D2] = eig(A'*A);
[D2,ord] = sort(diag(D2), 'descend');
S2 = diag(sqrt(D2));
V2 = V2(:,ord);

% eigenvectors of A*A' are the same as the left-singular vectors
[U2,D2] = eig(A*A');
[D2,ord] = sort(diag(D2), 'descend');
S3 = diag(sqrt(D2));
U2 = U2(:,ord);

% check results
A
U*S*V'
U2*S2*V2'
```

I get very similar results (ignoring minor floating-point errors):

```
>> norm(A - U*S*V')
ans =
   7.5771e-16
>> norm(A - U2*S2*V2')
ans =
   3.2841e-14
```

---

### EDIT:

To get consistent results, one usually adopts a convention of requiring that the first element in each eigenvector be of a certain sign. That way if you get an eigenvector that does not follow this rule, you multiply it by `-1` to flip the sign...

Comment: The norm will not change a lot, also in my code. But the difference between U2*S2*V2 and A is too big to ignore. I know that if t is an eigenvector then -t is also an eigenvector, but i need the specific sign for it to be exactly A. How do i fix that in my code?

Comment: @OriaGruber: see my edit about the sign convention. I'm not sure what convention MATLAB follows with regards to the sign..

Comment: Another thing: `eig` and `svd` return the eigenvalues (and corresponding eigenvectors) and principal values in different orders. I'm not sure about `eig`, but `svd` conveniently return them "in decreasing order."

Comment: @horchler: yes, `svd` are definitely sorted in decreasing order (according to the docs), while `eig` appears to be sorted in ascending order (the docs doesnt explicitly mention this), so `fliplr` might also work. Either way I am explicitly sorting the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of `eig` in my code above. Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3293855/97160

Comment: @OriaGruber: regarding the sign convention, you might be interested in these submissions: [eigenshuffle](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22885-eigenshuffle), [eigenshuffle2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29463-eigenshuffle2). Here are some related discussions as well: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/77590, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/306717. You'll find many more with a quick search...