# the Principal Component Analysis of weka returns wrong instances

Tags: components, weka, principal

I am using weka to do Principal Component Analysis,but the result must be wrong.

my instances are as follow:

40.4,24.7,7.2,6.1,8.3,8.7,2.442,20
25,12.7,11.2,11,12.9,20.2,3.542,9.1
13.2,3.3,3.9,4.3,4.4,5.5,0.578,3.6
22.3,6.7,5.6,3.7,6,7.4,0.176,7.3
34.3,11.8,7.1,7.1,8,8.9,1.726,27.5
35.6,12.5,16.4,16.7,22.8,29.3,3.017,26.6
22,7.8,9.9,10.2,12.6,17.6,0.847,10.6
48.4,13.4,10.9,9.9,10.9,13.9,1.772,17.8
40.6,19.1,19.8,19,29.7,39.6,2.449,35.8
24.8,8,9.8,8.9,11.9,16.2,0.789,13.7
12.5,9.7,4.2,4.2,4.6,6.5,0.874,3.9
1.8,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.8,1.1,0.056,1
32.3,13.9,9.4,8.3,9.8,13.3,2.126,17.1
38.5,9.1,11.3,9.5,12.2,16.4,1.327,11.6
26.2,10.1,5.6,15.6,7.7,30.1,0.126,25.9

my java codes are as follow:

```
PrincipalComponents pca = new PrincipalComponents();
pca.buildEvaluator(instances);
pca.setVarianceCovered(0.9);
instances=pca.transformedData(instances);
System.out.println(instances);
```

the results are as follow:

-0.76617,2.661828,-0.543741,0
-0.970913,0.436367,1.69961,0
2.881824,-0.434979,0.32666,0
2.202041,-0.118079,-0.265614,0
-0.055269,0.917633,-0.825503,0
-3.389144,-0.661234,0.756936,0
0.326235,-0.94073,0.256852,0
-1.020299,0.939242,-0.408135,0
-5.193605,-0.979272,-0.020702,0
0.337214,-0.689053,-0.018816,0
2.413215,0.213961,0.314493,0
4.426397,-0.617956,0.288353,0
-0.373545,0.837791,0.108058,0
-0.347075,-0.059153,0.119701,0
-0.470905,-1.506368,-1.788153,0

but I am sure the the correct result is as follow:

0.76617,2.661828,0.543741,0
0.970913,0.436367,-1.69961,0
-2.881824,-0.434979,-0.32666,0
-2.202041,-0.118079,0.265614,0
0.055269,0.917633,0.825503,0
3.389144,-0.661234,-0.756936,0
-0.326235,-0.94073,-0.256852,0
1.020299,0.939242,0.408135,0
5.193605,-0.979272,0.020702,0
-0.337214,-0.689053,0.018816,0
-2.413215,0.213961,-0.314493,0
-4.426397,-0.617956,-0.288353,0
0.373545,0.837791,-0.108058,0
0.347075,-0.059153,-0.119701,0
0.470905,-1.506368,1.788153,0

The sign(positive number or negative number) of the first column and the third column(the first principal component and the third principal component) is reversed.

I have search for the clue of my mistake on stackoverflow but I can not find my mistake,so dose somebody can find out is there something wrong with my code or weka code?

Comment: thank you very much for the answer of nekomatic,the result is not wrong,but the sign of each principal component is important because I want to plus the principal component to rank.So what is the key point if I use Principal Component Analysis for comprehensive ranking,or how could I deside the sign of the principal components and the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

Principal component analysis is based on finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the datasets, and [eigenvectors are not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152804/24447) - or put another way, [the definition of eigenvector is ambidextrous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154730/2894).

In PCA terms, you can negate all the **scores** for any principal component, as long as you also make the corresponding change to the **loadings**.

Where have you got the 'correct result' from? It looks as if it's a program or package that just happens to use a different convention from Weka.

Comment: I got the  'correct result' from a book I am reading,the datasets in my question are also from the book.the book teach me to use Principal component analysis to do comprehensive ranking.so if the The sign of the first column and the third column(the first principal component and the third principal component) is reversed,the rank is also confusion.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,I have see "eigenvectors are not unique " and "the definition of eigenvector is ambidextrous",I think if Principal Component Analysis is used for regression,we can negate all the scores or make the corresponding change to the loadings,but if Principal Component Analysis is used for comprehensive ranking,the sign of each principal component is important because I want to plus the principal component.so could you tell me what is the point if I use Principal Component Analysis for comprehensive ranking?